# JMeter CLI unix script clarification

Tags: jmeter, command-line-interface

The documentation about executing [JMeter CLI script](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) isn't clear,

What should be used in CLI? What JVM settings are problematic in each case?

Spec:

> **jmeter** run JMeter (in GUI mode by default). Defines some JVM settings which may not work for all
> JVMs.

> **jmeter.sh** very basic JMeter script (You may need to adapt JVM options like memory settings).

Why setenv.sh isn't called in jmeter.sh? why jmeter and jmeter.sh are separated scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking into wrong chapter, the correct one is **[1.4 Running JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running)** and according to it:

- **jmeter.sh**
  very basic JMeter script (You may need to adapt JVM options like memory settings).
- **jmeter** run JMeter (in GUI mode by default). Defines some JVM settings which may not work for all JVMs.

Also it you look at [line 19 of the `jmeter.sh` script](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/jmeter.sh#L19) you will see something like

```
## This is a simple wrapper for the script bin/jmeter
```

which means that **you're supposed to use `jmeter.sh`** either as it is or adapting it to your needs (given the nature of your question I wouldn't recommend making any changes however) and it will call `jmeter` which in its turn call `setenv.sh` under the hood which in their turn hopefully properly configure and start `ApacheJMeter.jar` binary file

A little bit more verbose and precise installation and execution instructions set: [How to Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)